# MVC 4: Displaying a List<> property on a view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model with a class like this

```
public class Feature
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public List<Camera> { get; set; }
}
```

and one like this:

```
public class Camera
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

I made a Controller and View for the Camera model, and added a couple of cameras with several Feature objects in their Features collection.

When I render the Camera views however (Index,Details,Edit), I don't see the Features field anywhere. In the Index and Details views I would like to see the items in the Features collection as multi-line text with one item per row.

How please?

Dave

PS: my next question is going to involve how to have the Edit view show a multi-select scroll list listing all items in the Feature table with the Feature items of the current camera already selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a DisplayTemplate.

To do so, add a folder called *DisplayTemplates* in *~/Views/Shared/* and add a PartialView named *Feature.cshtml*. Add the following code in your newly created PartialView :

```
@model Feature

<li>@Model.Desc</li>
```

Then in your view with your Camera model, do something like :

```
<ul>
     @Html.DisplayFor(e => e.Features)
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error : The type or namespace name 'Feature' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   How does it 'hook up' the code in the 2nd box to the code in the 1st box?  I mean, how does it know it is supposed to use the Desc when it sees the e.Features?

Comment: As for the Error for your 'Feature' class not been found, try putting the full namespace in front of your Feature class, like :
`@model MyNamespace.Feature`.

As for how the second code links to the first one, in the first one you define the way the Feature object will be displayed (it's a DisplayTemplate after all). In the second one you tell ASP.NET to display all the Features of your Camera.

Since your DisplayTemplate (_Feature.cshtml_) is in your folder "_~/Views/Shared/_, it will be used to display all objects of the type Feature that need to be displayed using `Html.DisplayFor()`.

Comment: I had to use MyNamespace.Models.Feature to get it to work, but that makes sense.  Thank you for explaining the hook ups.

Comment: Another question please...  In the DisplayTemplate, why is model lowercase in the first line and upper case in the second? What is the distinction?

Comment: On the first line, you define the type of your Model, using the Razor special syntax `@model`. On the second line you call the `Model` property of your view, that contains the instance of your Model.

Answer (score 0):

without any code from the controllers it's difficult to say, but a very common problem with Entity Framework is forgetting to use the `.Include()` extension method.  e.g. `var cameras = db.Cameras.Include(c => c.Features).ToList();`  which would give you a list of Cameras and associated features to pass to your view.

Also, if you add the virtual keyword to your Navigation Properties, Entity Framework can perform "Lazy Loading" where it automatically loads the associated items the first time they are accessed (server side).  In general, most Navigation Properties would also be defined as generic.  e.g.:

```
public class Feature
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
}

public class Camera
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you access to a much larger array of extension methods for filtering and sorting.  `IEnumerable` describes behavior, while `List` is an implementation of that behavior. When you use `IEnumerable`, you give the compiler a chance to defer work until later, possibly optimizing along the way. If you use `List` you force the compiler to reify the results right away.  In your case, using ICollection vs IEnumearable is necessary, since IEnumerable only allows list browsing, while ICollection defines a CopyTo method used by Entity Framework Internally.

Comment: You were right, no Include()...  but when I use "return View(db.Cameras.Include(c => c.Features).ToList());"  in the controller, I get the error "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyApp.Models.Camera' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Features'." even tho Intellisense shows the property in its dropdown and it is defined as you illustrated above.  Guess I missed something?

Comment: actually it was my mistake, since you have 2 collections referencing each other, you need to use ICollection<T> rather than IEnumerable<T>.  I'll update the answer.